# Select from column in dataframe based on value in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
dataDF <- data.frame(
          id = 1:5,
          to_choose = c('red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'yellow'),
          red_value = c(1,2,3,4,5),
          blue_value = c(6,7,8,9,10),
         yellow_value = c(11,12,13,14,15)
)

id to_choose red_value blue_value yellow_value
 1       red         1          6           11
 2      blue         2          7           12
 3       red         3          8           13
 4     green         4          9           14
 5    yellow         5         10           15
```

I want to create a new column `value`, which is the value from the appropriate column based on the to_choose column.

I could do this with an `ifelse` as follows

```
mutate(dataDF,
   value = ifelse(to_choose == 'red', red_value,
                  ifelse(to_choose == 'blue', blue_value,
                         ifelse(to_choose == 'yellow', yellow_value, NA))))
```

To give

```
id to_choose red_value blue_value yellow_value value
 1       red         1          6           11     1
 2      blue         2          7           12     7
 3       red         3          8           13     3
 4     green         4          9           14    NA
 5    yellow         5         10           15    15
```

But if there a simpler one line way of doing this along the lines of

```
mutate(dataDF, value = paste(to_choose, 'value', sep = '_'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dataDF %>% 
  gather(var, value , 3:5) %>%   
  mutate(var = gsub('_value', '', var))  %>% 
  filter(to_choose == var)
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R approach using `mapply`

```
dataDF$value <- mapply(function(x, y) if(length(y) > 0)  dataDF[x, y] else NA, 
      1:nrow(dataDF), sapply(dataDF$to_choose, function(x) grep(x, names(dataDF))))


dataDF

#  id to_choose red_value blue_value yellow_value value
#1  1       red         1          6           11     1
#2  2      blue         2          7           12     7
#3  3       red         3          8           13     3
#4  4     green         4          9           14    NA
#5  5    yellow         5         10           15    15
```

The idea is to get the appropriate row and column indices to subset upon. Row indices we are already know that we need to get value for each row of the dataframe. As far as getting the appropriate column is concerned we use `grep` over `to_choose` to find the column index from where the value needs to be extracted.